# Why is my Post request not returning the correct error?

Tags: express, axios

I have created a sever side request to handle a login. The request works as it should in postman. It also works as it should on the client side if I pass the correct login data to it. But when I try to make the request on my client side with incorrect data (such as an incorrect email or password) , It will only return a 401 error, when it should instead return a message of "Login failed at email" or "Login failed at password". But I can make the same request in postman with the same incorrect data and it will return to correct outcome.

Server side

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  let getUser;
  // finds user via email
  await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
  })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Login Failed at email",
        });
      }
      getUser = user;
      return bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Login Failed at password",
        });
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      let jwToken = jwt.sign(
        {
          email: getUser.email,
          userId: getUser.id,
        },
        "longer-secret-is-better",
        {
          expiresIn: "2h",
        }
      );
      res.status(200).json({
        token: jwToken,
        expiresIn: 600,
        user: getUser,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(401).json({
        message: err.message,
      });
    });
});
```

Client side request

```
import axios from "axios";

export const login = (userInfo) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: "SET_INFO_REQUEST",
  });

  try {
    await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "https://ecommersappbytim.herokuapp.com/auth/login",
      header: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      data: {
        email: userInfo.email,
        password: userInfo.password,
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_INFO_SUCCESS",
        payload: response.data.user,
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_INFO_FAILURE",
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

So again my only issue is when passing incorrect login data on the client side with axios, that it does not give me the return I am expecting

Comment: If you console.log the error variable in catch of axios promise, what you get?

Comment: I received nothing so its must be coming from my server side, I will look into the functionality of it closer